# How can you override class from Component package?

Tags: php, symfony

I am writing app using Symfony 2 and FOSUserBundle. I want to allow multiple users register with same name and use e-mails to identify them. I have edited users manager for this, turning loadUserByUsername into wrapper for findUserByEmail(). This broken TokenBasedRememberMeServices which uses getUsername() to generate remember me token. How can I replace that class with my own to dont force myself into hacking symfony files every time I update FW framework version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way:

Symfony bundles store class names in their configuration files params. You can simply overwrite those params by adding this line in config.yml:

```
# Parameters override
parameters:
    security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.class: MyVendor\UserBundle\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices
```

Comment: This usage is deprecated and removed as of 3.0. You can no longer do this and was already considered a bad practice. If you want to "replace" services, change their definition or decorate them.